# Android AdapterView?

Tags: android, android-adapterview

[Documents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts) say:

> When the content for your layout is dynamic or not pre-determined, you
>   can use a layout that subclasses AdapterView to populate the layout
>   with views at runtime. A subclass of the AdapterView class uses an
>   Adapter to bind data to its layout.

But most of tutorials are in about `ListView`,`GridView`,`Spinner` and `Gallery`.

I'm looking to extend a subclass directly from `AdapterView`. I have to create a custom view that it's content is dependent to an adapter.

How can I do this, and what methods must be overridden?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, you should be absolutely sure that `AdapterView` is what you want, because not all "dynamic or not pre-determined" views can be implement via `AdapterView`. Sometimes you'd better create your view extending `ViewGroup`.

if you want to use `AdapterView`, take a look at [this really nice example](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2010/05/20/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-1/). There are a lot of custom views with adapter on GitHub. [Check out this one (extends `ViewGroup`)](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView).

Answer (score 6):

This may not be a total answer to your question but i am showing you most probably a starting point or pointer which can guide you:

[Sony Developer Tutorials - 3D ListView](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2010/05/20/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-1/)

Answer (score 5):

`ListView` extends `AbsListView` which in turn extends `AdapterView<ListAdapter>`. So if you absolutely must implement such a custom view from scratch, you could have a look at the source code of those classes:

- [ListView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/ListView.java)
- [AbsListView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/AbsListView.java)
- [AdapterView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/AdapterView.java)

But beware, that's quite a task. Perhaps it may be sufficient to use one of the existing classes and tweak the look.

Answer (score 2):

Deriving from `AdapterView` can work, but it may not be as beneficial as you hope. Some of the infrastructure provided by `AdapterView` is package-private, meaning we don't have access to it.

For example, `AdapterView` manages the selected item index for `AbsListView` and `ListView`. However, because methods like `setNextSelectedPositionInt(int position)` (which is the only path to setting `mNextSelectedPosition`) are package-private, we can't get to them. `AbsListView` and `ListView` can get to them because they're in the same package, but we can't.

(If you dig into the `AdapterView` source you'll find that `setNextSelectedPositionInt()` is called from `handleDataChanged()`.  Unfortunately `handleDataChanged()` is also package-private and is `_not_called` from anywhere else within `AdapterView` that could be leveraged to enable setting position.)

That means that if you need to manage selected position, you'll need to recreate that infrastructure in your derived class (or you'll need to derive from `ListView` or `AbsListView`...though I suspect you'll run into similar problems deriving from `AbsListView`).  It also means that any `AdapterView` functionality that revolves around item selection likely won't be fully operational.

Answer (score -2):

You could create something like this :

```
public class SampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public SampleAdapter() {
  // Some constructor
}

public int getCount() {
  return count; // Could also be a constant. This indicates the # of times the getView gets invoked.
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position; // Returns the position of the current item in the iteration
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
  return GridView.INVALID_ROW_ID;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View view = null;

  view = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.some_layout, null);
  view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
view.setBackgroungColor(Color.RED);

  return view;
}
```

}

And this could be invoked like :

```
GridView sampleView = (GridView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.sample_layout);
sampleView.setAdapter(new SampleAdapter());
```

Comment: Thank you,but my question is not about `how create an adapter for a view`,my question is in about `how to create a custom view that it's content determined by an adapter?`(this view is called `AdapterView`.

Comment: this not what he @StudentStudent is asking about.