# Which android AdapterView do I need to use if I don't want a list?

Tags: java, android, android-adapterview

[image]

This activity has a fixed `Toolbar` on the bottom and the mid section (rest of the screen) is split in 2 equal parts (`LinearLayout` with weight 50). This mid section is handled by a fragment. Each sub part has exactly the same views in it. Of course while running the content is different.
On double tap I want BOTH (1 and 2 marked on the picture) to display new content. I do not want to be able to go back on previous Views. I also do not want a list-effect to display new content, I'd like a stacked effect but without CardViews, because you can't remove the space around the cards totally. Also, the next 2 views should appear instantly (I have the data stored locally).

How can I achieve that? Obviously I'm quite new to Android. It seems to me none of the ListView/GridView/StaggeredView does that, although what I need is easier since I basically just want to replace my content using an adapter to avoid recoding.

Comment: you just use visibility condition inside if to avoid the recoding,,

Comment: So on fragment creation I create 2 layers and one is hidden? How does the setup look like? Which `Adapter` do I use?

Comment: I cant get you.. what is adapter here ? or  else  just update a your tried code

Comment: Sorry I meant `AdapterView` as per this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681022/android-adapterview?rq=1
I did not find the proper View for my needs.

Comment: Here is what I am trying atm: I'm using a `RecyclerView` to populate my data with one single Item (I am changing my `ViewHolder` height inside the Adapter, then changing my `LayoutManager` to disable scrolling. I'll see if changing the position of the Items to replace content gets me where I want. Code to follow.